# Dask.groupby turns multiple partitions into one

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, dask

I have a `dask.dataframe`

```
df2 = dd.read_csv(path, dtype=dtypes, sep=',', error_bad_lines=False)
```

which is split into 220 partitions by `dask` itself

```
print(df2.npartitions)
>>220
```

I'd like to use `groupby` twice and save two dataframes into files

```
coccurrence_df = df2.groupby(['h1_h2', 'hashtag1','hashtag2','user_id']).count().reset_index()\
            .groupby(['h1_h2', 'hashtag1','hashtag2']).message_id.count().reset_index()\
            .rename(columns={"message_id":"coccurrence"})
strong_edges_df = coccurrence_df[coccurrence_df['coccurrence']>1].to_csv(path1, compute=False)
weak_edges_df = coccurrence_df[coccurrence_df['coccurrence']==1].to_csv(path2, compute=False)
dask.compute(strong_edges_df,weak_edges_df)
```

Why `coccurrence_df` is split into 1 partition when the dataframe it is created from is split into 220 partitions?

```
print(coccurrence_df.npartitions)
>>1
```

I believe because of this I'm losing parallelism, am I right?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groupby aggregations do parallel computation but result in a single partition output.  If you have many groups and want to have a multi-partition output then consider using the `split_out=` parameter to the groupby aggregation.

I don't recommend doing this though if things work ok.  I recommend just using the defaults until something is obviously performing poorly.